# Pass Options to Export[]

Tags: export, options

I'm working with Options to change the look and feel of some generated Graphics by passing Options to several functions, one of them being `Export[]`. For example:

```
Options[myPlot] := {Resolution -> 325, Size -> 12, FileName -> "A", 
  PlotStyle -> Automatic};

myPlot[f_, opts : OptionsPattern[myPlot]] := Block[{fig},
(* ... some calculations here *)
fig = Plot[f[x], {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}, 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]]];
fig = Show[fig, ImageSize -> OptionValue[Size]*72/2.54];+
Export[OptionValue[FileName] <> ".png", fig,  FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Export]]];
Print[fig];
]
```

And using `f[x_] := x^2` use the function as

```
 myPlot[f, Resolution -> 120, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

The Option to plot the function in `Red` is passed correctly to `Plot` but `Resolution` is not passed to `Export`. This is of course due to the fact that `Options[Export] = {}`.

My question is:

*How can I still pass Options to `Export` (i.e. how to determine, which are available, if they are not written in `Options[Export]`?*

And closely related:

*How to do that on your own, i.e. now I defined `PlotStyle` to be an Option of `myPlot`, though it's only passed on, how can I pass Options, that I haven't given myself, without getting the message*

> OptionValue::nodef: "Unknown option PlotStyle for ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Extraction of `Export` options

To extract the options for specific image export formats automatically, I really don't know an easy way. What you can do is to use `Trace` in combination with `ExportString` to investigate what *Mathematica* is doing. To make the next thing work you have to call e.g. `ExportString["test", "GIF"];` for every format at least once:

```
ExportString["test", #]; & /@ {"PNG", "GIF", "BMP", "JPEG"}

System`ConvertersDump`exportOptions /@ {"PNG", "GIF", "BMP", "JPEG"}
(*
{{"BitDepth", "ColorSpace", 
  "DataType"}, {"AnimationRepetitions", "Background", "FrameRate", 
  "TransitionEffect", "TransparentColor", 
  "UserInputFlag"}, {"BitDepth", "ColorSpace", "DataType", 
  "HorizontalResolution", "RLECompression", 
  "VerticalResolution"}, {"BitDepth", "ColorSpace"}}
*)
```

which is unfortunately very distinct from the documentation. For some exporters you find for instance such stuff

```
Options[System`ConvertersDump`exportGraphicsToGIFConverter]
(*
 {Background -> None, ImageResolution -> Automatic, 
 ImageSize -> Automatic, "ImageTopOrientation" -> Top, 
 "ColorReductionPalette" -> 256, "ColorReductionDither" -> True, 
 "GlobalColorMap" -> True}
*)
```

But how to find this automatically? I have no idea. Checkout this too

```
Options[System`ConvertersDump`exportToBitmapConverter]
Options[System`ConvertersDump`exportToColormappedBitmapConverter]
```

### Setting up options for own functions

Say you want to setup a function which can take its own options, options of `Plot` and options of `NMinimize`. Furthermore, you want to specify some of the default option-values for `Plot` and `NMinimize`. You can set the function up and use it like follows:

```
Options[f] = {
   fopt1 -> Automatic,
   fopt2 -> True,
   PlotStyle -> Green,
   AccuracyGoal -> 1
   };


f[x_, opts : OptionsPattern[{f, Plot, NMinimize}]] := Module[{},
  Print["Given Options usable by f only:", 
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[f]]];
  Print["Given Options usable by Plot only:", 
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[Plot]]];
  Print["Given Options usable by NMinimize only:", 
   FilterRules[{opts}, Options[NMinimize]]];

  Print["Defaultvalue for not specified options:" ];
  Print[OptionValue[StepMonitor]];
  Print[OptionValue[PlotRange]];
  Print[OptionValue[fopt2]];
]
```

Test case

```
f[x, fopt1 -> Full, PlotStyle -> Yellow, AccuracyGoal -> 42]
(*
Given Options usable by f only:{fopt1->Full,PlotStyle->RGBColor[1,1,0],AccuracyGoal->42}
Given Options usable by Plot only:{PlotStyle->RGBColor[1,1,0]}
Given Options usable by NMinimize only:{AccuracyGoal->42}

Defaultvalue for not specified options:
None
{Full,Automatic}
True
*)
```

And now you can pass any other option of `Plot` or `NMinimize` without a warning. But be carful, something like `Method` is an option for many functions and would be passed to each approapriate.

Comment: Already learned your last note the hard way when combining `ListPointPLot3D` and a `ParametricPlot3D` both using `ColorFunction` (used `Complement[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ListPointPlot3D]] , {ColorFunction}]` to deal with that), to use `ColorFunction` to colour just surface.

Comment: @Ronny In this case you can introduce your own `ParamPlotColFunc` and `ListPointPlColFunc` options and map then inside your implementation to the correct function.

Comment: That is of course the good way to do it, the code in the comment above was just to illustrate how to exclude some Options. In a white list type `Options` limitation the best way is yours.

Comment: As an answer to the extended version: Now, where i see, that it is quite complicated to get an automated way, maybe even @halirutan s way to introduce an own set of parameters that are passed down, might be a good idea to avoid too much work for the automated way.

Comment: ``System`ConvertersDump`exportOptions`` seem a good function. But don't work v12.0 anymore...