# How to find the options available for a function?

Tags: export, options, optional-arguments

I was trying to create an animated .gif with Mathematica. I knew that the function to use was

```
Export["animation.gif",tableplot]
```

where `tableplot` contains the table of my plots. However, I also know that when creating a .gif, you can tune the duration of each frame. Looking at Wolfram Documentation Center for `Export`, I have not been able to identify how this duration could be selected.

Fortunately, looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109786/how-to-generate-animated-gif-of-a-manipulate-8-0-1), I found that the correct argument was

```
Export["animation.gif",tableplot,"DisplayDurations" -> 0.5]
```

It appears that the description of the available options could be found in the documentation under the ones associated with `GIF`.

However, how could one find the name of the option `"DisplayDurations"`, if one does not have access neither to this thread neither to the Documentation ? Is there a way to find **programmaticaly** all the possible options associated to the `Export` as a .gif ? More generally, if I have a function `f`, is there a way to know all the possible options `f` can receive ?

Comment: *"DisplayDurations"* is an option for the `GIF` format not for the `Export` function. Follow the link provided by  Öskå. You may want to read [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15272/pass-options-to-export#answer-15280).

Comment: @Öskå @rhermans Thank you a lot : now I feel stupid for my question... ^^ More generally, if I give you a function `f`, is there a way to know all the possible options `f` can receive ?

Comment: Always read the **Details** section of the documentation. Loot at [`Options`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Options.html?q=Options) and its friends, [`AbsoluteOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AbsoluteOptions.html). I hope you don't mind, but this questions will be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: @rhermans If needed, this question can also of course be deleted, to keep the site clean.

Comment: @Öskå Please elaborate and I could retract my vote. As I see it this options should be searched in the docs for the format.

Comment: @Öskå Ok, vote retracted. I trust the question will be edited.

Comment: You can find manual pages on the individual formats in the doc. ctr.  The pages for `Import` and `Export` have a link near the top "Listing of Formats."  Entering "GIF" in the search field yields the GIF page, which is quite extensive and explains several things about `"DisplayDurations"`.  The documentation of some formats seems less extensive or there is less to explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of export to gif options are here.

```
Options[System`ConvertersDump`exportDataToGIFConverter]
```

Obviously not all. As far as I can see in principle all Export[] and Import[] options are here

```
(Save["stdout", #] & /@ Names["System`ConvertersDump`*"])
```

As you can see they are hardcoded in a number of different functions. 
If you look only for export to GIF options, then I would restrict searching tosomehow smaller set of definitions, i.e. Names["System`ConvertersDump`*GIF*"].

You can extract all options using string manipulations like this:

```
nb = CreateTemporary[];
(Save[nb, #] & /@ Names["System`ConvertersDump`*GIF*"]);
str = Import[nb, "Text"];

Union[StringCases[str, "\"" ~~ LetterCharacter .. ~~ "\"" ~~ " -> " ]]
```

> {"\"AnimationDisplayTime\" -> ", "\"AnimationRepetitions\" -> ", \
>       "\"Background\" -> ", "\"BitDepth\" -> ", "\"ColorMap\" -> ", \
>       "\"ColorReductionDither\" -> ", "\"ColorReductionPalette\" -> ", \
>       "\"ColorSpace\" -> ", "\"Comments\" -> ", "\"Data\" -> ", "\"DataType\
>       \" -> ", "\"DisplayDurations\" -> ", "\"DitheringMethod\" -> ", \
>       "\"Format\" -> ", "\"FrameCount\" -> ", "\"Frames\" -> ", \
>       "\"GlobalColorMap\" -> ", "\"Graphics\" -> ", "\"ImageCount\" -> ", "\
>       \"ImageOffset\" -> ", "\"ImageSize\" -> ", "\"ImageTopOrientation\" -> \
>       ", "\"Interlaced\" -> ", "\"RawData\" -> ", "\"ReadGIFData\" -> ", \
>       "\"RepeatAnimation\" -> ", "\"TransitionEffect\" -> ", \
>       "\"TransparentColor\" -> ", "\"UserInputFlag\" -> "}

Sure, not the best way, but at least partly works.

Comment: Well, that's already [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15272/pass-options-to-export) :)